# pickadate Angular - Tradução

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Estou utilizando o Angular pickadate só que ele está em inglês, preciso deixar em português, alguém poderia ajudar?
Segue código:

```
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
     selectMonths: true, 
     selectYears: 15,
     language: 'pt-br'
  });
```

Coloquei language, porém não funciona.

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well-sm no_right" datepicker-options="inlineOptions" style="float:left; width: 100%;"></uib-datepicker>
```

Únicos códigos que utilizo para carregar o calendário.

Calendário utilizado: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para traduzir, utilizei o locale pt-br do próprio Angular, segue link para visualização:

http://imasters.com.br/front-end/javascript/serie-angularjs-usando-locale-angularjs-parte-04/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Answer (score 1):

Por default, o Angular suporta o locale en_US. Para outras formatações é preciso adicionar .js específico para o país, então basta você baixar o arquivo que contém as traduções do Datepicker.

Segue um exemplo que fiz no [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ObzeURVVuqYW9gyafo8N?p=preview).
No exemplo adicionei no header do html o script que contém a tradução do calendário e o Angular fez a troca do idioma.

Você pode encontrar o arquivo .js que contém a tradução do Datepicker  nesse repositório do [GitHub](https://github.com/renato/bower-angular-locale-pt-br)